# How to deal with so big database

Tags: mysql

i were working on a project and this project contain so big database 
my database increasing  `60.000 rows` each day 
and until today i have more than

```
 15 million rows
```

just in one of my tables

i start to fell that my phpMyAdmin  start to slower than before

and the same problem when i try to fetch data and display it on the web

please how can i deal with this problem

i start to  fear   about the future 
any help please ? ? ?

Comment: This is way too broad and unclear for anyone to say anything. No database schema, no queries, no plans - there are no general things that anyone can say. Please add a lot more information.

Comment: Hire database experts and let them take care of it, this language barrier here and lack of knowledge on your part can't be fixed in a single SO answer.

Comment: Make sure you've got appropriate indexes in place.

Comment: It sounds like you have been given an assignment that you are not trained for yet. You should let your employer know that you are out of your depth and you need to be an assistant to someone who is expert with this work, so you can learn. It's not fair for you to be given responsibility you're not ready for. And it's not realistic for you to take the job if you can't do it. You need to get a job you can be successful doing, with opportunities to grow your skills. You can't expect to become an expert only by asking questions on Stack Overflow. You need a mentor.

Answer (score 2):

Well, 15 million rows isn't incredibly large by today's standards. I'm pretty sure your main concern should be hardware.  Get your hands on as much disk performance (SSD's) and RAM as you can.

Another problem that you'll probably have to deal with is the sheer number of queries you can handle at a given time. It's likely that you'll have to move to a master/slave config so that *READ* queries can run against the slaves while the *WRITE* queries run against the master.

For any more specific answers, you're going to have to provide a lot more detail.